# Simulating a click on a Next/Done button in Robolectric

Tags: android, robolectric

In a given screen i have few controls where the first one is `EditText` and than `RadioGroup`  and than a `Button`, at `EditText` i have used   `android:imeOptions="actionNext"`, now for this writing a straightforward `Robolectric` test case is not a big deal as
we can write

```
Button someButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.some_button);
someButton.performClick();
```

but the question is how to automate and write  a test case on clicking `Next/Done button` of the given softinput KeyBoard. How we can write  and perform next/done Button of softinput keyboard  click ?

Please guide!!

Answer (score 8):

You've got probably something like this which you want to test:

```
getView(R.id.etPassword).setOnEditorActionListener(
            new OnEditorActionListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                        KeyEvent event) {
                    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
                        checkCredentialsAndStartLoginTask();
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

This listener is called when you click on "Next" on the soft keyboard. If you want to test this simply call the onEditorAction with the adequate actionId as parameter on the EditText to simulate this soft keyboard button click. See this sample.

```
@Test
public void emptyUsernameShouldTriggerToast() throws Exception {
    activity = controller.create().start().resume().visible().get();

    // enter username and password
    ui.etAccount.setText(""); 
    ui.etPassword.setText("Battery");

    // test initial state
    ui.etPassword.onEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);

    // test Toast
    ShadowHandler.idleMainLooper(); 
    assertThat( ShadowToast.getTextOfLatestToast() ).isEqualTo(("Please enter username and password.") ); 
}
```